# Re-stage All Files in Local Git Repo

Tags: git

I did a stage and commit before doing an initial git remote add.
Consequently here's what I see and it's not able to commit my staged files.

> How can I reset/restage all files as if I started from scratch and committing for the first time to this new repo?

[image]

So here's what I see now if I look at status.  It doesn't recognize any changes.

[image]

Comment: Have you already committed to your local repo, and just need to push to remote? You don't re-stage files to push to remote, you just push your local commits. Posting `git log` output might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're confused about pushing and committing.

You **committed** your files locally, then added a remote.
This is fine.

Now you can simply **push** your files to the remote repo, using

```
git push -u origin master
```

where `-u` will save the tracking information so that in the future you will be able to just use

```
git push
```